# How can I get longitude and lattitude from address or street?

Tags: r, dictionary, geolocation, ggmap

I need to get coordinates from a fair amount of addresses, or at least from the street name and postal code.

```
get_coord(street_name,postal_code) # would give lat & lon
```

Can I do this with `ggmap` ?

Comment: Looks like you got it figured out?  If you did, go ahead and mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I can, I skimmed the manual too fast:

```
library(ggmap)
geocode("Eiffel Tower")

#       lon      lat
# 1 2.294481 48.85837
```